# deleting a char array pointer trigger a mysterious breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, pointers, breakpoints

I have the next following code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void test(char arr[], int size){
    char* newA = new char[5];
    delete[] arr; // this line cause the breakpoint
    arr = newA;
}

void main(){
    char* aa = new char[5];
    test(aa,5);
    aa[0] = 's';
}
```

When I run this code I see that the variable "aa" at index zero is 's' then the breakpoint is triggered.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzcw6.png

Comment: Does it help if the first parameter of `test()` is a `char*` instead of a `char[]`? While pointers and arrays are similar, I could see that potentially causing the exception when calling `delete[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `arr` by value, so this line

```
arr = newA;
```

has no effect in the caller side. So you are reading from a deleted array here:

```
aa[0] = 's';
```

This is undefined behaviour. You can fix this in three ways:

Pass a reference:

```
void test(char*& arr, int size) { .... }
```

Return the pointer:

```
char* test(char* arr, int size) {
  delete[] arr;
  return new char[5];

}
```

Or, better, use well behaved standard library types such as `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpfull. Enother question, why the breakpoint was triggered in my Visual Studio while in other it wasn't?